# Homestead/Vagrant - Symfony - PhpStorm can't use Validate Debugger Configuration on Web Server to finish xdebug config

Tags: php, symfony, vagrant, phpstorm, homestead

As the title said, I'm trying to use Xdebug on a Symfony website with PhpStorm.

As the debug isn't working as soon as it gets to file located within the VM, asking me to add a path to them, I'm trying to solve this problem by following this [procedure](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2016/06/debugging-vvv-vagrant-setup-with-phpstorm/).

But I can't manage to make the Validate Debugger Configuration on Web Server work, I get

> Specified URL is not reachable, caused by: 'Request failed with status code status 404'

I've added pictures of the different informations I've prepared for PhpStorm, if you need anything more, don't hesitate to ask

PhpStorm Validate Page:

[image: PhpStorm Validate Page]

Deployment Server settings with connection OK:

[image: Deployment Server settings]

SSH configuration also successfully connecting:

[image]

I'd really like to get Xdebug working so if you can help, this would be really appreciated.

Comment: 1) Did you properly set up the Deployment entry? Can you use it to deploy changed files? 2) Deployment, Mappings tab -- are all fields filled correctly there? 3) What URL gets requested by PhpStorm that returns 404 error -- check your web server error log. The file that PhpStorm is trying to upload should be in the website root; 4) Does the website URL work in the browser?;